# Is there a way I can kill all while dead in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

In the Sky Factory Mod Pack, I keep getting killed by player mobs standing over my bed that don't burn in sunlight. Every time I spawn, the game lags, I hear the sound of being hit about 8 times, and it puts me back onto the death screen.

Is there a way I can kill all the mobs crowding on my bed while dead in Minecraft?

Comment: ...just curious, how did that happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try downloading [MCEdit](https://github.com/Khroki/MCEdit-Unified) and opening up your world. You should see the mobs represented as red boxes around your bed; highlight them by clicking and dragging a selection around them, and then press `Delete Entities`. This doesn't remove actual players, but it will affect any items/xp on the ground, so be careful.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are in single player, exiting to the menu, setting the difficulty to peaceful and reloading the world should remove all hostile mobs.

You can then change the difficulty back immediately and continue as you were.

Comment: Difficulty is now per world and can't be set from the main menu, so this may be impossible. Keep in mind that this will remove all hostile mobs everywhere in the loaded area, including boss and named mobs. Also, I'm uncertain but, I don't think Sky Factory player mobs are removed on peaceful.

Comment: @colorfusion Er, I still see a difficulty button in the main menu options... I was uncertain if every mod mob would be removed, but if they stay, that seems like a bug.

Comment: Regardless, it's still a viable method for vanilla and certain mod-packs.

Comment: My bad, I was looking at a 1.8 client; it is still present in 1.7.10.

Comment: Per-world difficulty is easy enough to change via an NBT editor though!

Answer (score 2):

If you open the chat before you die by pressing the command button (By default `/`), you can enter commands while dead. This means knowing when you'll die and pressing `/`, the entering the command properly.

**Edit: This has been patched as of 1.8.1, and will no longer work**